# how do I create a dataframe based on values from another dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

i have a data frame, from this I created another dataframe,
which consists of a selection after a number of conditions. The result is a number of countries that satisfy the condition n > 11.
Now I want to continue working with only these countries. How can I copy values from the first dataset based on the countries in the selection?

My first df looks like:

[image]

and the second (so the selection of countries):

[image]

In my final df I need every column and row from my 1st df (but only for the countries present in the second df)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about your data and reason using second dataframe, but let first and second data as `df1` and `df2`, then

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  filter(Country.o... %in% df2$Country.o...)
```

(I cannot find out what is the column name. You should not post your data as an imange)

Comment: That is exactly what I meant. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Two options -

1. Do an inner join

   a) Base R -

```
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by = 'Country')
```

b) `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)
df3 <- inner_join(df1, df2, by = 'Country')
```

2. Instead of creating `df2` from `df1`, I would just filter the 1st one to get the resulting dataframe.

```
df3 <- df1 %>% group_by(Country) %>% filter(n() > 11)
```